# How to ignore logs when some LogicalThreadContext.Property have certain value in log4net

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, log4net

I am using ADO.NET appender with MySQL as backend DB

I have added following in my appender settings

```
<parameter>
      <parameterName value="_context" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="25" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
        <key value="Context" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>

    <filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
      <key value="Context" />
      <stringToMatch value="Transaction" />
      <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
    </filter>
```

What I am doing is logging lots of scenario. But I wanted to skip logs going to DB command when Context Property has value ="Transaction"

But it seems to be not working.
Please let me know what I need to correct

P.S.

I have even tried out following

```
public class CustomFilter : FilterSkeleton
{

    private readonly IList<IFilter> filters = new List<IFilter>();        
    public override FilterDecision Decide(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        if (loggingEvent == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("loggingEvent");

        if (filters.All(x => x.Decide(loggingEvent) != FilterDecision.Accept))
        {
            return FilterDecision.Neutral;
        }

        // All conditions are true
        if (AcceptOnMatch)
            return FilterDecision.Accept;
        else
            return FilterDecision.Deny;
    }

    public IFilter Filter
    {
        set { filters.Add(value); }
    }

    public bool AcceptOnMatch { get; set; }

}
```

with

```
  <filter type="MyNameSpace.CustomFilter,  MyAssembly">

      <filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
        <key value="Context" />
        <stringToMatch value="Transaction" />
        <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
      </filter>      
    </filter>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
      <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
      <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
      <levelMax value="FATAL" />
    </filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

So it is possible after all.

There is a `loggingEvent.GetProperties()` that gives the custom fields.

You `CustomFilter` could look something like this:

```
    public class CustomFilter : FilterSkeleton
    {
        private readonly IList<IFilter> _filters = new List<IFilter>();
        public override FilterDecision Decide(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            if (loggingEvent == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggingEvent));

            var properties = loggingEvent.GetProperties();
            if (properties != null && (properties[Key] as string ?? properties[Key]?.ToString()) == StringToMatch )
            {
                return AcceptOnMatch ? FilterDecision.Accept : FilterDecision.Deny;
            }

            if (_filters.All(x => x.Decide(loggingEvent) != FilterDecision.Accept))
            {
                return FilterDecision.Neutral;
            }

            // All conditions are true
            return AcceptOnMatch ? FilterDecision.Accept : FilterDecision.Deny;
        }

        public IFilter Filter
        {
            set => _filters.Add(value);
        }

        public bool AcceptOnMatch { get; set; }

        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string StringToMatch { get; set; }
    }
```

I have not tested it with multiple filters, but this is a start.

Comment: I am using LogicalThreadContext.Properties to add this properties. don't know why it is not there in loggigEvents.Properties but shown in loggingEvent.GetLoggingEventData()

Comment: I am having problem in arranging the filters. can you please help in it. Please check the combination i have tried at https://github.com/microknights/Log4NetAdoNetAppender/issues/13